# Not sure how to connect the Pigeonhole principle to maximal clique size in finite graphs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, pigeonhole-principle

Please see edit.

I am currently stuck at a proof where to my understanding the key step is to argue how the fact that if in a subgraph, the degree of each vertex is at least the size of the largest clique in the graph $G$, $d(v) \geq \omega(G), v \in V(G)$, then the original assumption of ... is false. My guesses are that

1.) the contradiction is something like: "if $d(v) \geq \omega(G)$, then the subgraph contains a clique larger than the largest clique in the original graph".

2.) contradiction can be constructed somehow with pigeonhole principle from the fact that i.) the vertex set $V(G)$ is finite, ii.) self-loops are not allowed, iii.) each vertex $v$ is connected to $\omega(G)$ other vertices.

My current problem is that I don't know how to argue about the contradiction in general. I can give a constructive argument about a single graph, in which the aforementioned facts lead to a contradiction, but I don't know whether this is enough to argue in general.

The constructive argument about a single graph is that suppose there are in total $\omega(G) + 2$ nodes. Partition the nodes as $T_1 = \{r\}, T_2 = \{v_1, v_2,\dots,v_{\omega(G)}\}, T_3 = \{e\}$. Let the root node $r$ to be connected to all nodes in $T_2$. Connect all nodes in $T_2$ other than $v_1, v_2$ to each other. Then connect $v_1$ to all nodes in $T_3 \cup T_2 \setminus \{v_2\}$, and $v_2$ to $T_3 \cup T_2 \setminus \{v_1\}$. Now $d(x) = \omega(G), x \in T_1 \cup T_2$. But now, if $e$ is connected to the required remaining $\omega(G) - 2$ nodes there exists a clique with size $\omega(G) + 1$, which is a contradiction.

Edit: The graph $G$ is an interval graph.

Comment: "if $d(v)\geq \omega(G)$, then the subgraph contains a clique larger than the largest clique in the original graph" - you won't get this in general: there are graphs with arbitrarily large minimum degree which do not even contain a triangle (i.e. for which $\omega(G) = 2$), for example complete bipartite graphs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"if $d(v) \geq \omega(G)$, then the subgraph contains a clique larger than the largest clique in the original graph"

Above statement is not true

**Counterexample:**
Please see the below graph. It contains a subgraph $\{1,2,3\}$, where the degree of each node is $4$, i.e. larger than the maximum clique size in the original graph, but the graph G does not have clique larger than size 3.

[image: Graph with 6 nodes and 6 edges]

Comment: Hmm, I see. Does the argument change in any way if we are given that the supergraph (original graph $G$) is an interval graph?

Comment: Ok Consider graph on intervals in [0,2]. $I_0 = [0,1],I_1=[1,2]$ which intersect. Now let $I_{2i} = [1-\frac{1}{2i},1-\frac{1}{2i+1}]$ and $I_{2i+1} = [1+\frac{1}{2i+1},1+\frac{1}{2i}]\quad \forall i \in[1,\infty)$. Then degree of $I_0$=degree of $I_1 = \infty$. But max clique size is still 2.